# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_13 to have shape (None, 6) but got array with shape (6, 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am training a classification network with training data which has X.shape = (1119, 7) and Y.shape = (1119, 6). Below is my simple Keras network with and output dim of 6 (size of labels). The error which is returned is below the code

```
hidden_size = 128
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(7, hidden_size))
#model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1,7)))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=6, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_13 to have shape (None, 6) but got array with shape (6, 1)
```

I would perfer not to do this in tensorflow because I am just prototyping yet it is my first run at Keras and am confused about why it cannot take this data. I attempted to reshape the data in a number of ways in which nothing worked. Any advice as to why this isn't work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `Dense(output_dim=6, activation='softmax'))` must be changed to `Dense( 6 , activation='softmax'))`

Comment: There's no problem with your model. You should give data processing and training code.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably remove the parameter `return_sequences=True` from your last LSTM layer. When using `return_sequences=True`, the output of the LSTM layer has shape `(seq_len, hidden_size)`. Passing this on to a Dense layer gives you an output shape of `(seq_len, 6)`, which is incompatible with your labels. If you instead omit `return_sequences=True`, then your LSTM layer returns shape `(hidden_size,)` (it only returns the last element of the sequence) and subsequently your final Dense layer will have output shape `(6,)` like your labels.

Comment: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_17: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2` is the error I receive if I attempt this.

Comment: Is `lstm_17` the first or second LSTM layer? The first LSTM needs `return_sequences=True`, the second one doesn't. Also, your input `X_train` should have shape `(batch_size, seq_length)`.